# Relation between a function on $N$ sphere and a function on $(N-1)$-cell.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $S^N$ be a unit $N$-sphere. Let $f:S^N\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Let $\bf{\Sigma}$ be a unit $(N-1)$-cell, consider the function $g:S^N\to\bf{\Sigma}$ such that, for any $\hat{a}\in S^N$,  $g(\hat{a}) = \hat{\theta} = [\theta_1,\theta_2,...\theta_i..\theta_{N-1}]$, where $$\theta_i = \frac{\arccos(\hat{e_i} \cdot\hat{a})}{\pi} $$,$i = 1,2,3...(N-1).$, and $\{\hat{e_1},\hat{e_2},...\hat{e_i},...\hat{e}_{N-1}\}$ are the first $(N-1)$ vectors of the Euclidean basis of $\mathbb{R}^N$.We know $g$ is one to one and onto, and hence there exist $g^{-1}:\bf{\Sigma}\to S^N$ which is one to one and onto. Define a function $f_c:\bf{\Sigma}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that, given any $\hat{v}\in \bf{\Sigma}$, $f_c(\hat{v}) = f(g^{-1}(\hat{v}))$.

Hence for any given $f$, there exists a unique $f_c$ with this type of relation. So I'd like to know, given any such $f$, obtaining $f_c$ in this fashion, is there any standard terminology relating $f$ and $f_c$. Like $f_c$ is the "so and so" transform of the function $f$?

Comment: A $(N-1)$-cell is [0 1]x[0 1]x....(N-1)times...x[0 1].
For example, A 2-cell is the square region with vertices (0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1).

Comment: Clearly, your definition of the N-sphere is wrong. Also: Do you realize that arccos is not a function (it is multivalued).

Comment: @studiosus : Please be a bit constructive and explain what you mean.

Comment: N-sphere is an N-dimensional manifold sitting in N+1 dimensional space.

Comment: @studiosus : What is the alternative terminology that fits here, I mean in two dimensions, I call it a unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Please let me know if any suitable term exists for it.

Comment: @studiosus : Somehow adjust with the arccos thing, let it take (0,2pi) or what ever nice and give me an answer! Otherwise I need functions for each of $2^N$ quadrants, which i cannot afford at this time, so assume accordingly. Lets assume $f$ is somewhat regular or smooth as required, if need be

Comment: @studiosus : or Lets just stick to one quadrant only

Comment: So an $(N-1)$-cell is $[0,1]^{N-1}$. Since $g:S^N\to\Sigma$ is $1-1$ and onto, it seems that instead of $S^N$, you mean $S^{N-1}$, the $N-1$ dimensional sphere in $\mathbb{R}^N$. For example, $S^1$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^2$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @studiosus: usually, $\arccos(x)$ means the [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of the inverse cosine. That is $\arccos(x)\in[0,\pi]$.

Comment: @robjohn: And this convention prevents the function g from being injective. I think OP got it by now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are considering (N-1)-dimensional sphere in the N-space. The function g you wrote should be treated as a partially defined map on the sphere (only then you can take its inverse). For N=2, this function is called called "polar coordinates"(let is just call them $\theta$-coordinates in higher dimensions). In higher dimensions, I do not think there is a standard name, people  tend to use "hyperspherical coordinates" instead. The composition $f_c$ you are asking about has a somewhat longish name: Function $f$ written in $\theta$- coordinates.